# Changing colour of row if a certain aspect is met

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a list of clients that send in certain information to me and I have setup columns to enter a tick using (`=char(10004)`) on R,S,T,U,V,W,X & Y columns and I need to colour them to go green when all the columns have the tick in them.

How can I do this please?

Comment: Have you checked the help for "conditional formatting"?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data begins with Row 2. Then apply the following conditional formatting formula to the range `R2:Y` (or `R2:Y100` if your data ends in row 100):

```
=COUNTIF($R2:$Y2, "="&char(10004))=8
```

Here, `COUNTIF` counts the cells with the checkmark; if there are 8 of them, formatting is applied.

---

And here is a version that applies formatting if there are no blank cells in the range.

```
=COUNTBLANK($R2:$Y2)=0
```

Comment: Thank you for that is there a way that I can if all the boxes are filled in then the entire row will change colour and not fill in if one cell is empty

Comment: Added to the answer.